# Changing Window Title

Tags: 2013

I've been trying to change the window title shown at the top of the browser and on the tabs.

I've used the following code which gets me halfway there.  (We have Sharepoint 2013)

```
    <!--MS:<SharePoint:PageTitle runat="server">-->
        <!--MS:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">-->
        <!--ME:</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>-->
    <!--ME:</SharePoint:PageTitle>-->
```

But unfortunately it prefaces my page name with "Pages -" and I can't seem to get rid of that.  I want the tab and browser title to say "**TestTest**" instead of "**Pages - TestTest**".

I'm sure it's something simple but i can't seem to get it. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

[image: top of browser image]

Comment: I've tried all the suggestions, some of which i've seen before.  Thanks to all!  But nothing is working. :-(

I forgot to add that I'm doing this in the HTML version of my masterpage.  Does that make a difference? I think it does.

Comment: Did you found a solution for this? My only way is to change it in the PageLayout for the site, where I remove the "<SharePointWebControls:ListProperty Property="Title" runat="server"/> - " in the contentPlaceholder PlaceHolderPageTitle.

Comment: @emo -- what you've done is the correct solution to this question. Using jQuery to change this is totally unnecessary.

Comment: I think this answers the question better. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/175434/change-page-title-tag/175435#175435

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this link described how to do that:
http://www.topsharepoint.com/change-title-tag-on-sharepoint-sites

using jQuery also you can fix it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        document.title = 'My Page';

    });

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I used the info in the link you included.  My main error was thinking i did this in the masterpage when i should have been doing it page layout.

Comment: This is totally unnecessary. Just go to your page layouts and remove "<SharePointWebControls:ListProperty Property="Title" runat="server"/> - " in the contentPlaceholder PlaceHolderPageTitle

Comment: Necessary or not, it beats making the change on every single page layout.

Answer (score 1):

Please try with the following:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceholderID="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
    <SharePointWebControls:FieldValue ID="PageTitle" FieldName="Title" runat="server"/>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or this!

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:ProjectProperty Property="Title" runat="server"/>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me from the browser...

1. click edit page
2. in the ribbon click edit properties
3. enter the desired tab name in the Document Title field
4. SAVE & Publish / check in