# Change page title tag

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem

On SharePoint, your page tag is displayed as "ProjectName PageTitle" where project name is the Title of your site collection and page title is the name of your page.

Obviously, this is unflattering. How can you change this to make it look better?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your page layout (I am referring to the .html here) in SharePoint designer.
2. Click Edit
3. At the top of the page make your modification here:

   `<!--MS:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">-->
   <!--CS: Start Page Field: Title Snippet-->
   <!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="PageFieldFieldValue" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
   <!--MS:<PageFieldFieldValue:FieldValue FieldName="fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247" runat="server">-->
   <!--ME:</PageFieldFieldValue:FieldValue>-->
   <!--CE: End Page Field: Title Snippet--> |
       <!--MS:<SharePoint:ProjectProperty Property="Title" runat="server">-->
       <!--ME:</SharePoint:ProjectProperty>-->
   <!--ME:</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>-->`
4. In this instance I have changed the Page Title to appear as **"Page Title | ProjectName**

That's it. You now have nice Page Title tags that are not an eye sore.

> *P.B: This change can only be made in the Page layout not the master page*